# Date difference between non-consecutive rows with random time differences and group between rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have looked through a number of different questions already and there isn't anything that can answer this question.

Basically we have a list of users and they fall under different categories. This categories can be duplicated meaning someone can be in category A for a few rows and then B for two rows then back to A over a sequence of time and there is no set number of rows in each category or if they will duplicate or not. The table shows the first three columns that are in the database and I have added in the other two columns at the end showing what I want to be able to calculate and how.

[image]

What I want to do is work out the time that a user is in a category based on the first time they are in that category and the first time they move to the new category. If they jump from category A to B then back to A, category A should be treated as a separate category.

Have been playing around different options with no avail so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per category, you can use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select userid, category, datetimestart,
       lead(datetimestart) over (partition by userid order by datetimestart) as datetimeend
from (select t.*,
             lag(category) over (partition by userid order by datetimestart) as prev_category
      from t
     ) t
where prev_category is null or prev_category <> category;
```

You can get the difference using whatever method you prefer.  Because this avoids aggregation, this should be the fastest method.

And, if you want to remove the `END` row, then use the above as a subquery or CTE and filter in the outer query.

Comment: I had been playing around with lead and lag but didn't think to put it in a sub-query

Comment: The data isn't perfect so for lag(category) over (partition by userid order by datetimestart), I updated to lag(category) over (partition by userid order by datetimestart, categroy) as sometimes two rows with different categories will have the same time - it shouldn't be the case but unfortunately these scenarios sneak through

Answer (score 0):

...data gaps&islands (many answers on this in SO)

```
declare @t table(userid int, category char(1), datetimestart datetime);

insert into @t(userid, category, datetimestart)
values
(1, 'A', '20210212 08:10:02.000'),(1, 'A', '20210212 08:11:10.000'),
(1, 'B', '20210212 08:12:20.000'),(1, 'B', '20210212 08:14:30.000'),
(1, 'A', '20210212 08:15:20.000'),(1, 'A', '20210212 08:16:10.000'),(1, 'A', '20210212 08:18:40.000'),
(1, 'C', '20210212 08:19:05.000'),(1, 'C', '20210212 08:25:41.000'),
(2, 'A', '20210212 08:10:20.000'),(2, 'A', '20210212 08:14:10.000'),
(2, 'B', '20210212 08:29:05.000'),(2, 'B', '20210212 08:35:41.000'),
(2, 'A', '20210212 08:40:20.000'),(2, 'A', '20210212 08:44:10.000');

select 
    userid, category,
    min(datetimestart) as startdatetime,
    max(datetimestart) as enddatetime
from
(
    select userid ,category,
    case when lead(category) over(partition by userid order by datetimestart) = category 
        then datetimestart
        else lead(datetimestart, 1, datetimestart) over(partition by userid order by datetimestart) 
    end as datetimestart,
    row_number() over(partition by userid order by datetimestart)
    -
    row_number() over(partition by userid, category order by datetimestart) as groupid
    from @t
) as t
group by userid, category, groupid
order by userid, startdatetime;
```

Comment: . . If you look carefully at the desired results, you'll see that this doesn't produce the same results as the OP is asking for.